# how to use git to make commits from two different machines

Tags: git

I am new with git.

I have a project on git. I would like someone else to get the repository, make changes and check their changes back into the repository.

Before that I would like to do this from a different machine that I have

what is the procedure to do this?

should the repository be cloned on the machine?

Comment: What have you done so far? Is your repository hosted, like on github.com?

Comment: yes. it is hosted on github.com.  that is where i'd like the other machine to checkin changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to collaborating on GitHub, there are two policies:

1/ [**Forking**](http://help.github.com/forking/)

This is the recommended path.
Basically, your colleague:

- clone your repo (called *upstream*) into his repo (on GitHub, called *origin*),
- clone his GitHub repo (*origin*) on his desktop (*local*),
- and do whatever he want between his *local* repo and his GitHub repo *origin*.

He will only push to *origin* because he is not allowed to push on *upstream* (the ssh-based authentication would fail on your *upstream* repo)

Whenever he wants you to integrate in your GitHub repo some changes, he will make "**[pull request](http://github.com/guides/pull-requests)**" (through his GitHub repo admin UI), notifying you of some commits to apply.
See [this script](http://gist.github.com/64519) by [Andre](http://earthcode.com/blog/2009/02/merge_a_github_pull_request_wo.html) for automating the process.

2/ [**Granting commit access**](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/)

That is a less safe route, where you add his public ssh-key to the list of users/keys allowed to push directly to your upstream repo.
See "**[Managing Collaborators](http://github.com/guides/managing-collaborators)**".

Answer (score 2):

Commits in git are always done in a local clone of a repository. The idiomatic way to share changes in git is to `git pull` from a remote repository to "pull in" any changes.

For example, you can clone Linus Torvalds' linux kernel repository by doing

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git
```

Then, you could regularly pull in new changes by doing

```
git pull
```

The repository is omitted here in the pull command, because it defaults to the originating repository.

If you have an interesting patch for the linux kernel, then you might make your repository publicly available by [hosting it with gitosis](http://tech.libersoft.it/2009/git-repository-hosting-in-5-minutes-with-gitosis-in-debian-lenny/) or other software. Then you would just have to convince Torvalds to `git pull` from you ;-)

Typically developers will also distinguish between their "private" and "public" repositories. You can use "git push" to push changes from your private to your public repository.

Comment: my code is already on github. So you suggest that the other person should pull all the code...create their own repository and i should get their changes and merge mine?